# Simple way to count the vowels in a string?

Tags: php

If I define a simple string variable, how would I count and output the number of vowels in the string in the simplest possible way?

I have searched and found a number of similar ways to do so, but most seem more complex than necessary.  They are all functional and maybe the complexity IS necessary, but I am looking for the simplest solution possible.

My string variable would be something like:

```
$someString = "This is some text with some more text and even more text."
```

I just want to display the total instances of a,e,i,o,u.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Although this certain problem might not really affect performance, but you should look for the least complexity first and then try to simplifiy as possible. Actually you should always, when possible, think instead of making the processor think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an easy solution:

```
<?php
$string = "This is some text with some more text and even more text.";
echo "There are <strong>".preg_match_all('/[aeiou]/i',$string,$matches)." vowels</strong> in the string <strong>".$string."</strong>";
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

Why not just

```
$Vowels = substr_count($someString, 'a')+substr_count($someString, 'e')+substr_count($someString, 'i')+substr_count($someString, 'o')+substr_count($someString, 'u');
```

I would, however, encase it in a function otherwise you would have to change the names of the variables every time you want to reuse it:

```
function CountVowels($String) {
    return substr_count($String, 'a')+substr_count($String, 'e')+substr_count($String, 'i')+substr_count($String, 'o')+substr_count($String, 'u');
}

echo CountVowels('This is some text with some more text and even more text.');
//Echos 17
```

--

**2018 Update:**

This could be much neater as

```
function count_vowels(string $s): int {
  return array_sum(array_map(function ($vowel) use ($s) { 
    return substr_count($s, $vowel); 
  }, ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']));
}

count_vowels('This is some text with some more text and even more text.');
```

However, as others pointed out, this may not be the fastest on long strings since it has to iterate through the string 5 times.

Comment: Note: this might be slower than actually iterating through (though, because it is a predefined function, it might be faster)

Comment: Really smart! but takes much more performance than it deserves.

Comment: You forgot to add an "i" in your code. This is how it looks with the "i": `$Vowels = substr_count($someString, 'a')+substr_count($someString, 'e')+substr_count($someString, 'i')+substr_count($someString, 'o')+substr_count($someString, 'u')+substr_count($someString, 'i');`

Comment: @Amy not sure what you're talking about, the i is there in all 3 of my examples. Your code has it twice and will be wrong

Comment: Oh sorry, I must've not seen that.

Answer (score 3):

untested but should work:

```
$matches = preg_match_all('/[aeiou]/i', $someString, $ignore);
```

Comment: I think the pattern has to be in a string.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it...

```
$vowels = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');

$vowelsCounts = array_sum(
                 array_intersect_key(
                  array_count_values(
                   str_split(
                    strtolower($str)
                   )
                  ),
                  array_flip($vowels)
                 )
                );
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4b2mH2).

**But**, this works too, just make sure you don't operate this on the original string, as it will change it.

```
str_replace($vowels, FALSE, $str, $vowelsCounts);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FjaNOK).

Answer (score 2):

I know it's quite late, but I've tested all answers above and performance wasn't good when handling big string.

I believe this code is better on memory and execution time

```
$counter = 0;
$a = array("a","e","i","o","u");
foreach (count_chars($str, 1) as $k => $v) {
    //echo "There were $v instance(s) of \"" .$k."/". chr($k) . "\" in the string.\n";
    if(in_array(strtolower(chr($k)), $a))
        $counter += $v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('#[aeiou]#i', $someString, $matches);
echo count($matches) - 1, "\n";
```

Something like this ought to work.  I can't think of a simpler method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$someString = "This is some text with some more text and even more text.";
echo preg_match_all('/[aouie]/i', $someString, $out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not suited for strings in multibyte character sets.

```
function countSpecificChars ($string, $charsOfInterest) {
    $count = 0;
    $len = strlen($string);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        if (in_array($string[$i], $charsOfInterest)) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}

function countVowels ($string) {
    return countSpecificChars($string, array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'));
}

echo countVowels('This is some text with some more text and even more text.');
// echoes '17'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$someString = "This is some text with some more text and even more text.";

$total = 0;
$vowels = Array('a','e','i','o','u');

for ($i=0;$i<strlen($someString);$i++)
{
    for ($j = 0;$j<5;$j++)
        if ($someString[$i] == $vowels[$j])
        {
            $total++;
            break;
        }
}
echo $total;
```

Comment: I think you'd want to make that `continue 2`.

Comment: @alex: Oh no! it shouldn't be continue at all, but rather `break` to end the entire second `for` loop at once.

Comment: `break` and `continue 2` should do the same thing, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Count the vowel in string using function in php.

```
echo substr_count("£string","a")+substr_count("£string","e")+substr_count("£string","i")+substr_count("£string","o")+substr_count("£string","u");
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follow:

```
public static function count($string)
{
    preg_match_all('/[aeiou]/i', $string, $matches);
    return count($matches[0]);
}
```