# How to check the vowels in the word

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

If I define a simple word variable, how would I count and output the number of vowels in the word in the simple way?

I have searched and found a number of similar ways to do so, but most seem more complex than necessary, but I am looking for the simplest solution possible.

My word variable would be something like:

```
$word = "Apple"
```

I just want to ***display the total instances of a,e,i,o,u***.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Create a map containing all vowels, iterate over every letter in the word, if the current letter is in the vowels_map increment a counter, return the counter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450399/counting-number-of-vowels-in-a-string-with-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465304/simple-way-to-count-the-vowels-in-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$string = "This is some text with some more text and even more text.";
echo "There are <strong>".preg_match_all('/[aeiou]/i',$string,$matches)." vowels</strong> in the string <strong>".$string."</strong>";
?>
```

I hope it will help you