# I just want to get a list of words from an array which has more and less than 3 characters but separately how can i do that?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, structure

```
$name   = array('jake', 'rita', 'ali', 'addert', 'siryteee', 'skeueei', 'wsewwauie', 'aaaaweefio');
$vowels = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
$massiv = [];
$vowel  = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {

    $massiv[] = $name[$i];

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($vowels); $j++) {
        $vowel[] = $vowels[$j];
    }
}
if (count($massiv[$vowel] >= 3) {
    print_r($massiv);
}
```

Comment: i mean only vowels.the list of words which has more and less than 3 vowels in a word

Comment: `if (count($massiv[$vowel] >= 3) {` "`)`" missing

Comment: Please show us an expected output. Are you looking for 2 arrays or to simply output the names?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php might be part of what you need

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php might help as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7465353/296555

Comment: it does not help i need a full code

Comment: Then tells us what you want your output to look like.

Comment: @roma When you say more or less than 3 vowels, you mean 3 `types` of vowels or 3 vowels itself?

Comment: the title must be changed! it's hard to guess what you want!

Comment: Given the input that you presented, show us what you want your output to look like. Exactly. Otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to count the number of vowels.

> I just want to get a list of words from an array which has more and
>   less than 3 characters but separately how can i do that?

I am assuming you want 2 arrays that contain a list of names with more than 3 vowels and the other with less than 3 vowels. Note - I intentionally left out names that have 3 vowels because I don't know which list I should put them in. You should be able to add that in easily enough.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/69f838a4dca56f651a521854636212c545dddbb2

```
<?php
$names = array('jake', 'rita', 'ali', 'addert', 'siryteee', 'skeueei', 'wsewwauie', 'aaaaweefio');

$moreThanThree = [];
$lessThanThree = [];

foreach ($names as $name) {

    $count = preg_match_all('/[aeiou]/i', $name, $matches);

    if ($count > 3) {
        $moreThanThree[] = $name;
    }

    if ($count < 3) {
        $lessThanThree[] = $name;
    }
}

// You now have 2 arrays - $moreThanThree & $lessThanThree

var_dump($moreThanThree);
var_dump($lessThanThree);
```